# How to handle inline table-valued function that returns a table using ado.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I have implemented Inline table valued function in sql. I am trying to read the table values returned from Inline table valued function in C# using ado.net. Please help. I am attaching code here.

### Sql function:-

```
CREATE FUNCTION fun 
(   
    @lname varchar(50)
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
    select fp.accntname,ld.BU,fp.salesop,idt.isdormant from legacy_system as ls
inner join fourth_page as fp on ls.accountname=fp.accountname
inner join linked as ld on fp.productid=ld.productid
inner join isdormant as idt on idt.productid=ld.productid
inner join legacy_system as l on ls.productid=idt.productid
where l.legacyname in(@lname)
)
GO
```

### C# code:-

```
 [HttpPost]
            public void call_stored_procedure(List<string> lyname)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(lyname);
                string dogCsv = string.Join(",", lyname.Select(i => "'" + i + "'"));
                Console.WriteLine(dogCsv);
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("data source=.; database=Srivatsava; integrated security=SSPI"))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        command.CommandText = "select dbo.fun(@lname)";
                        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", dogCsv);
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        String s=command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                        Console.WriteLine(s);
                        connection.Close();
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Table valued function returns a table so to read the result your commandtext should be

```
command.CommandText = "select * from dbo.fun(@lname)";
```

Now you are using ExecuteScalar() function to execute your command .

From MSDN  - **[ExecuteScalar()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx)**

> Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in
>   the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are
>   ignored.

So even though your function is returning recordset with multiple columns , only the first column of first row s returned.

If you need to read full recordset returned by the table valued function , you need to use ExecuteReader() function.

[**ExecuteReader()**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Sends the CommandText to the Connection and builds a SqlDataReader.

Answer (score 0):

All the below link are `related to your question` .. it's already solved.. so please `before post any question` .. please look it already has answer/solved  or not ..

[Calling SQL Defined function in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17047057/calling-sql-defined-function-in-c-sharp)

[How can I call a SQL function in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796530/how-can-i-call-a-sql-function-in-c)

[Calling SQL Functions directly from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013192/calling-sql-functions-directly-from-c-sharp)