# How to call a tsql function inside a vb.net function?

Tags: vb.net, t-sql, function, return-value, call

I arrive from years with Oracle plsql.
Now I'm trying vb.net

I created a function that return a char value, so written:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [abc].[GET_PERSON_TYPE]
( 
@person_national_id CHAR(16)
)
RETURNS CHAR(1) AS
BEGIN 

declare @person_type CHAR(1)

SET @person_national_id = (
                SELECT p_type
                FROM abc.persons
                WHERE national_id = @person_national_id
                )

RETURN @person_national_id

END
```

The question: I will create a function get_type(...) in vb.net that calls the tsql function written above...
how can I call the tsql function [abc].[GET_PERSON_TYPE] in vb.net function get_type(...) function?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: See here for a good discussion of similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300052/how-can-i-call-a-sqlserver-function-from-vb-netor-c-is-there-some-syntax-lik

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can call the function directly but you can use it in a select statement.

```
select [abc].[GET_PERSON_TYPE]('abcde')
```

Comment: You can `EXEC` scalar functions.

Comment: @Martin - Did not know that. So basically you could call the function the same way you call a stored procedure from the client. I know nothing about vb.net but I tested in Delphi and it works fine to call the function in the same way as you would execute a stored procedure.